# Different date time format of the user causing an error

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetime-format, unhandled-exception, string-to-datetime

My application is giving an error on different installation based on their different date/time format which my codes are based on

for example below original code ;

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DTPTarihSec.ValueChanged
    Dim BaslangicTarihi As Date
    Dim BitisTarihi As Date


    BaslangicTarihi = "16/04/1996" 'TCMB kayıtları en eski bu tarihe kadar
    BitisTarihi = Date.Today

    If hatasayac = False Then
        SecilenTarih = DTPTarihSec.Value
    End If

    hatasayac = False

    If (SecilenTarih > BitisTarihi) Then

        MsgBox("İleri tarihli kur bilgileri bulunmamaktadır. Lütfen uygun bir tarih giriniz. " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
               "Kurların geçerli olduğu en son tarihe yönlendirildiniz !", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "TCMB Döviz Kurları")
        hatasayac = True
        If Now.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Cumartesi" Or Now.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Saturday" Then
            SecilenTarih = Date.Today.AddDays(-1)
            DTPTarihSec.Value = Date.Today.AddDays(-1)

        ElseIf Now.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Pazar" Or Now.DayOfWeek.ToString = "Sunday" Then
            SecilenTarih = Date.Today.AddDays(-2)
            DTPTarihSec.Value = Date.Today.AddDays(-2)

        Else
            SecilenTarih = Date.Today
            DTPTarihSec.Value = Date.Today

        End If


    End If
```

is giving following error on one of the user computer ;

***Unhandled exception has occurred in your application... If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
Conversation from string "16/04/1996" by type 'Date' is not valid.***

This is because of the following code line ;

```
 BaslangicTarihi = "16/04/1996" 'TCMB kayıtları en eski bu tarihe kadar
BitisTarihi = Date.Today

If hatasayac = False Then
    SecilenTarih = DTPTarihSec.Value
End If
```

but it is not giving error on my computer.

My question is about ;How to handle this error which will prevent all different date and time format on different computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use string to populate a date variable, use a date.

```
Dim BaslangicTarihi = New Datetime(1996, 04, 16)
```

I would suggest you turn Option Strict On.

Also, you should properly use the enum for DayOfWeek instead of the string.

```
If Now.DayOfWeek = Day​OfWeek.Saturday Then
```

Comment: can you please also advice about the problem how can i set the users date/time format to the same with the application in order to not get further error?

Comment: @Ali your code should always use Date not string, that way you'll never have that problem. As for displaying, using the user computer format is the way to go since they decided they wanted to date in that format.